# What would the ploidy of a multinucleate cell be?

Tags: cell-biology

If we have a haploid organism, and it undergoes karyokinesis without cytokinesis, would the organism be considered haploid or diploid?

Answer (score 1):

Ploidy is generally defined in terms of the number of chromosomes in the nucleus, rather than the number of chromosomes in the cell.

Some examples in support of this:
- A paramecium has [a diploid micronucleus and polyploid macronucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramecium#Reproduction_and_sexual_phenomena)
- Muscle cells are generally considered diploid even though they have multiple nuclei
- The additional chromosomes in mitochondria and chloroplasts are not considered to make cells polyploid, even if [the organelle itself may be polyploid](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/632240v2.full).

Thus, I would assess a cell such as you describe to be haploid, albeit with two nuclei.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you so much!